# Drupal htaccess rewrite rules not always working

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, osticket

I am having trouble with my htaccess for Drupal.  I am using osticket and am finding it hard to get the syntax right.  When I use the below I can't always respond to tickets and get a page not found error.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/support/"
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

If I edit to show below I can respond but the ajax stops working (which causes issues when creating new tickets ect).

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/support/"
 RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

The interesting thing is it does not happen all the time.  Sometimes I use the first set or rules and I can respond to tickets no problem.  Other times I get the not found error.  Why would it work sometimes but not others?

I have been using the link below to troubleshoot.

https://www.drupal.org/node/30334